# What is the rating on different suits of armor in SS13?

Tags: space-station-13

There is a wide variety of different types of armor to protect from damage in SS13, from basic body armor to the HoS's Trenchcoat to hardsuits to spacesuits and even no suits at all.

If I'm looking for the maximum amount of defense against assault, what armor should I grab first?  Is there a particular rate at which armor absorbs damage?  Does a firesuit offer more protection from burns than it does blunt damage?